# OpenSSL libs: 2 on Linux libcrypto and libssl and more than 13 on windows. What shall I link on windows to compile my sample?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2010, openssl, sha256

So I look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262386/generate-sha256-with-openssl-and-c/2458382#2458382) sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "openssl/sha.h"

void sha256(char *string, char outputBuffer[65])
{
    unsigned char hash[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    SHA256_CTX sha256;
    SHA256_Init(&sha256);
    SHA256_Update(&sha256, string, strlen(string));
    SHA256_Final(hash, &sha256);
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        sprintf(outputBuffer + (i * 2), "%02x", hash[i]);
    }
    outputBuffer[64] = 0;
}

int sha256_file(char *path, char outputBuffer[65])
{
    FILE *file = fopen(path, "rb");
    if(!file) return -534;

    byte hash[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    SHA256_CTX sha256;
    SHA256_Init(&sha256);
    const int bufSize = 32768;
    byte *buffer = malloc(bufSize);
    int bytesRead = 0;
    if(!buffer) return ENOMEM;
    while((bytesRead = fread(buffer, 1, bufSize, file)))
    {
        SHA256_Update(&sha256, buffer, bytesRead);
    }
    SHA256_Final(hash, &sha256);

    sha256_hash_string(hash, outputBuffer);
    fclose(file);
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    static unsigned char buffer[65];
    sha256("string", buffer);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
}
```

What libs shall I link to my project to compile this on windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the [pre-compiled DLL](http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) flavor of OpenSSL and it works fine for me.

Comment: I know how to compile tham but with what of tham to link my app?

Comment: You link with the import .lib file that belongs to the DLL.  Or, to the static .lib library if you are not compiling OpenSSL into a DLL. Look for `libeay32.lib` and `ssleay32.lib`.

Comment: It can not find `sha256_hash_string`