# How to link boost properly?

Tags: c++, linker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GCC: Use OpenSSL’s SHA256 Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784434/gcc-use-openssls-sha256-functions)

I keep getting these linker errors although I specified boost.

```
~/cli$ make
g++ -pthread -lboost_system-mt -lboost_program_options-mt -lboost_thread-mt
-lboost_filesystem-mt ./main.o -o cli
./main.o: In function `main':
/home/mistapink/cli/main.cpp:123: undefined reference to
`boost::program_options::options_description::m_default_line_length'
```

The system is Ubuntu with 32 Bits. The boost libraries are installed in `/usr/lib/` with aptitude.

Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong? I am a bit lost on this.

Comment: See e.g. [this old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13784484/440558) of mine.

Comment: Well, the description isn't, the underlying problem and solution definitely are.