# reconfiguring a Makefile

Tags: unix, makefile

I'm a little new to this and am trying to build a rather large project. In particular, the source code is executing the lines

```
gcc -Wall -W   -c -o setitimer-helper.o setitimer-helper.c
gcc -lm  setitimer-helper.o   -o setitimer-helper
```

This creates a linker error because according to this [C: Undefined reference to floor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14743023/c-undefined-reference-to-floor)
-lm now must come after the object files.

I need to know where in the source code I can find and rearrange this. I think it's in here, but I'm unfamiliar with Unix.

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -W
LDFLAGS = -lm

all: setitimer-helper squish-pty squish-unix

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@

%: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

clean:
    rm -f *.o setitimer-helper squish-pty squish-unix
```

Am I correct? If so, how can I fix this. If not, where should I look?

Thanks.

Comment: Try ` $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)`. Your `%.o: %.c` rule will never be used, as make can create the binary from the c file with your other rule.

Comment: You should be aiming for your build to look like. `gcc setitimer-helper.c   -o setitimer-helper -lm`.

Comment: That was my first guess. Going to give it a go, thanks.

Comment: @PaulRooney right, I ran that command manually to confirm it works before posting on here that it was the intended goal.

Comment: Also you could just delete both rules and allow the default rules to handle it.

Comment: The first try worked. I don't want to mess with it anymore. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Change the rule to build your binary to put `$(LDFLAGS)` at the end.

```
%: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)
```

When executed the `gcc` command should look like.

```
gcc -Wall -W setitimer-helper.c -o setitimer-helper -lm
```