# undefined reference to `ftdi_init'

Tags: c, ubuntu

I have used libftdi in the past and compiled using the command:

```
gcc -lftdi -o i2csend i2csend.c
```

Everything went fine.
Today, on Ubuntu 12.10 I get many errors such as `` undefined reference to `ftdi_init' ``

I understand that libftdi was renamed to libftdi1 so I tried the same command with `-lftdi1` and got error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lftdi1
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [GCC: Use OpenSSL's SHA256 Functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784434/gcc-use-openssls-sha256-functions)

Answer (score 5):

You should typically not directly specify external package's library names.

It's better to use the packaging system's help program, i.e. [`pkg-config`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkg-config), like so:

```
$ gcc -o i2csend i2csend.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libftdi1)
```

Note that this assumes that the package name is `libftdi1` in `pkg-config`'s database; I'm not sure how to verify this portably. You can run `pkg-config --list-all | grep ftdi` to find out.

It's generally a good idea to keep the libraries part (`-l` option) at the end of the command line, which the above is doing. It's somewhat cleaner to factor out the `CFLAGS` part, but that requires repeating the command:

```
$ gcc $(pkg-config --cflags libftdi1)  -o i2csend  i2csend.c  $(pkg-config --libs libftdi1)
```

Here, I've used double spaces to separate the logical parts of the command line for improved clarity.

Comment: you have to **always** warn people not to move their sources to the end of the command line (I learned it the hard way here on SO). They **always** tend to do it for some fscking aesthetical reasons.