# Undefined reference to `initscr' Ncurses

Tags: c, compilation, linker, ncurses, undefined-reference

I'm trying to compile my project and I use the lib ncurse. And I've got some errors when compiler links files.

Here is my flags line in Makefile:

```
-W -Wall -Werror -Wextra -lncurses
```

I've included ncurses.h

Some layouts :

```
prompt$> dpkg -S curses.h
libslang2-dev:amd64: /usr/include/slcurses.h
libncurses5-dev: /usr/include/ncurses.h
libncurses5-dev: /usr/include/curses.h

prompt$> dpkg -L libncurses5-dev | grep .so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurses.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmenu.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libform.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpanel.s
```

And here are my erros :

```
gcc -W -Wall -Werror -Wextra -I./Includes/. -lncurses -o Sources/NCurses/ncurses_init.o -c Sources/NCurses/ncurses_init.c
./Sources/NCurses/ncurses_init.o: In function `ncruses_destroy':
ncurses_init.c:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `endwin'
./Sources/NCurses/ncurses_init.o: In function `ncurses_write_line':
ncurses_init.c:(.text+0xc5): undefined reference to `mvwprintw'
./Sources/NCurses/ncurses_init.o: In function `ncurses_init':
ncurses_init.c:(.text+0xee): undefined reference to `initscr'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: possible duplicate of [GCC: Use OpenSSL's SHA256 Functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784434/gcc-use-openssls-sha256-functions). And many, many more...

Comment: And you learn the hard way that `-l<lib>` is not a *flag*, but rather a *directive* ;)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need to change your makefile so that the `-lncurses` directive comes *after* your object code on the gcc command line, i.e. it needs to generate the command:

```
gcc -W -Wall -Werror -Wextra -I./Includes/. -o Sources/NCurses/ncurses_init.o -c Sources/NCurses/ncurses_init.c -lncurses
```

This is because object files and libraries are linked in order in a single pass.

Comment: Note that this demonstrates showing your "flags in Makefile" was insufficient, since your question actually doesn't exhibit the problem. An expert had to intuit it from experience.

Comment: how do you do this with a Makefile?

Comment: @CpILL: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Answer (score 6):

In C++ , I fixed it just by linking the ncurses library .

> Here is the command :

```
g++ main.cpp -lncurses
```

Comment: the -lncurses flag also solved my issue when compiling with gcc.

Answer (score 2):

I got flags to correct order by using LDLIBS variable:

```
ifndef PKG_CONFIG
PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
endif

CFLAGS+=-std=c99 -pedantic -Wall
LDLIBS=$(shell $(PKG_CONFIG) --libs ncurses)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
man gcc | grep -A10 "\-l library"
```

> -l library
>
> Search the library named library when linking.  (The second alternative with the library as a separate argument is only for POSIX
>   compliance and is not recommended.)
>
> It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the linker searches and processes libraries and object files
>   in the order they are specified.  Thus, foo.o -lz bar.o searches
>   library z after file foo.o but
>              before bar.o.  If bar.o refers to functions in z, those functions may not be loaded.