# How to set the last line in terminal fixed for input while the application is doing a lot of printf?

Tags: c++, linux, unreal-engine4

I want to set the last input line on my terminal as fixed, so that everything that is printed from the application doesn't interfere with the user's input. I'm making an Unreal Engine 4 plugin, but I need to manage the Linux terminal input.

I tried getting the input with cin, and it works, but I don't know how to separate the user's input from the application output.

```cpp
std::string input;
getline(std::cin, input);
char inputchar[input.size() + 1];
strcpy(inputchar, input.c_str());
UE_LOG(LogServerConsole, Warning, TEXT("Current Input: %s"), *FString(inputchar));
```

Comment: Not possible with standard C++, which has nothing to say about terminals. I guess you have to look to some Linux library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, it is absolutely possible to do what you're asking using [ANSI escape sequences](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php). However, just because it is *possible* does not mean it is *easy*; these are very low-level primitives that have to be built up.

**Ncurses** is a higher-level library for doing more complicated things in a terminal window. I encourage you to read about it [here](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/programming-text-windows-ncurses) and many other places online to see if it meets your needs.

Comment: Thank you! I tried to include pdcurses library with Visual Studio 2019 but I'm getting undefined symbol: initscr even if I included curses.h

Comment: Are you linking with `-lncurses`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16192087/undefined-reference-to-initscr-ncurses

Comment: I'm cross compiling with clang for windows, because I'm using Unreal Engine 4, so how can I do that?

Comment: Not sure. If you have access to the compiler options, just add `-lncurses` to the end. See if [this](https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/c-gameplay-programming/3268-how-to-specify-compiler-and-compiler-options) helps.

Comment: Ok, I think that the real problem is how to compile pdcurses on windows and produce a .so library. I downloaded gnuwin32 but when I compile with make, I get this error: https://i.imgur.com/rwVOpWB.png

Comment: The translation is: "Cannot find the specified file"

Comment: This is starting to become a different question. I suggest opening a new question to fix the make error, but only after you research to make sure your question has not already been answered.