# Generate SHA256 in c++

Tags: c++, sha256

I need to generate SHA256 of some data. I found [this example](http://www.zedwood.com/article/cpp-sha256-function) is a very good one. Now my question is Can I generate a sha256 by using my own key.

**EDIT:**

First of all, sorry for wrong question. I don't mean that to change the key used to generate SHA256. I really need is that, to convert the following java code to c++

```
public static String calculateHMAC(String data, String key) throws Exception {
String result;
try {
    // get an hmac_sha2 key from the raw key bytes
    SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), HMAC_SHA2_ALGORITHM);

    // get an hmac_sha1 Mac instance and initialize with the signing key
    Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA2_ALGORITHM);
    sha256_HMAC.init(signingKey);

    // compute the hmac on input data bytes
    byte[] rawHmac = sha256_HMAC.doFinal(data.getBytes());

    // base64-encode the hmac 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char[] charArray = Base64.encode(rawHmac);
        for ( char a : charArray){
            sb.append(a);
            }
        result = sb.toString();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new SignatureException("Failed to generate HMAC : " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: sha is a hash function not an encrypt scheme

Comment: Thanks. Tag removed.

Comment: Then what do you mean with your "own key"?

Comment: Are you mixing up salt with an encryption key?

Comment: Why would you change it?  the whole point of SHA256 is that anyone can run it on a piece of data and compare the result it to a known good value to confirm the integrity of the data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend the free [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/) library. Here's a sample for [HMAC](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/HMAC).

Answer (score 11):

**Edit (as OP changed the question):**

There are lots of C++ libraries available for cryptographic operations:

1. [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) (My personal choice, we use this library in our industry products).
2. [Crypto++](https://cryptopp.com/).

Here's an example of [Generate sha256 with OpenSSL and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262386/generate-sha256-with-openssl-and-c/10632725).

**OLD ANSWER:**

SHA-256 is a member of [SHA-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) cryptographic hash functions family, which usually generates 256 bits or 32 bytes *HASH* code from an input message.

It's not an "encryption" mechanism which means, from the HASH (also known as message digest or digest) **you can not regenerate** the message.

Therefore, we do not need any "keys" to generate `SHA-256` message digest.

Moreover, hash functions are considered practically *impossible* to invert, that is, to recreate the input data from its hash value (message digest) alone. So You can't "decrypt" a HASH message/message digest to its input message, which concludes reversing is not possible for Hashing. For example,

```
SHA256(plainText) -> digest
```

Then there is **NO** mechanism like `inverseSHA256` which can do the following,

```
// we cannot do the following
inverseSHA256(digest) -> plainText
```