# Why does NULL terminating a sha256 hash crash when using dynamic memory but not static memory?

Tags: c, memory, hash, openssl

I'm using openssl's libcrypto library to try and create a sha256 hash of a arbitrary input buffer, however when I null terminate the hash buffer to make it a C string it crashes but only when using dynamic memory returned from `malloc` but not when I use statically allocated memory like in this example: [generate sha256 with openssl and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262386/generate-sha256-with-openssl-and-c). I'm allocating 65 bytes just like the example, as shown by the `length` value being printed. So why does null terminating the buffer crash when using dynamic memory as opposed to static memory?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>

static int sha256(char *in, char **out)
{
    int rtrn, i;
    SHA256_CTX sha256;
    unsigned char hash[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    rtrn = SHA256_Init(&sha256);
    if(rtrn < 0)
    {
        printf("Sha Init Error\n");
        return -1;
    }

    rtrn = SHA256_Update(&sha256, in, strlen(in));
    if(rtrn < 0)
    {
        printf("Sha Update Error\n");
        return -1;
    }

    rtrn = SHA256_Final(hash, &sha256);
    if(rtrn < 0)
    {
        printf("Sha Final Error\n");
        return -1;
    }

    *out = malloc((SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2) + 1);
    if(*out == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't allocate output buf\n");
        return -1;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        sprintf(*out + (i * 2), "%02x", hash[i]);
    }

    printf("Length: %d\n", (SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2) + 1);

    *out[64] = '\0';

    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    int rtrn;
    char *input = "3r98h932hr934hor";
    char *output;

    rtrn = sha256(input, &output);
    if(rtrn < 0)
    {
        printf("Sha256\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("%s\n", output);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `NULL` is a null pointer constant, not to be confused with the null character `'\0'`.

Comment: @Keith Thompson Thanks, for the distinction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect this is because you did not mean:

```
*out[64] = '\0';
```

but rather:

```
(*out)[64] = '\0';
```

Array subscripting (`[]`) has [higher precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than the indirection (`*`) operator in C, so what you wrote is the equivalent to:

```
*(out[64]) = '\0';
```

which will be corrupting a random area on the stack (where the `char **` lives).