# Is there a standard way of representing an SHA1 hash as a C string, and how do I convert to it?

Tags: c++, c, hash, openssl

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918676/generate-sha-hash-in-openssl) is about how to create an SHA-1 hash from an array of data in C using the [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) library.

It returns an array of 20 bytes, containing the hash. Is there some standard way of representing that data in string form, not binary?

If so, is there a function in OpenSSL itself to convert to said string format?

If not, how should it be done? Of course, I can dream up my own encoding, use base64 or what not, but is there some canonical format?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Usually hashes are represented as a sequence of hexadecimal digits (naturally, two per byte). You can write the code to write such thing easily using an `ostringstream` with the right modifiers:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

std::string GetHexRepresentation(const unsigned char *Bytes, size_t Length) {
    std::ostringstream os;
    os.fill('0');
    os<<std::hex;
    for(const unsigned char *ptr = Bytes; ptr < Bytes+Length; ++ptr) {
        os<<std::setw(2)<<(unsigned int)*ptr;
    }
    return os.str();
}
```

Arguably, this can also be done more efficiently (and, to my today's eyes, more clearly) "by hand":

```
#include <string>

std::string GetHexRepresentation(const unsigned char *Bytes, size_t Length) {
    std::string ret(Length*2, '\0');
    const char *digits = "0123456789abcdef";
    for(size_t i = 0; i < Length; ++i) {
        ret[i*2]   = digits[(Bytes[i]>>4) & 0xf];
        ret[i*2+1] = digits[ Bytes[i]     & 0xf];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

or with good old `sprintf`, probably the easiest-to-read method of all:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

std::string GetHexRepresentation(const unsigned char *Bytes, size_t Length) {
    std::string ret;
    ret.reserve(Length * 2);
    for(const unsigned char *ptr = Bytes; ptr < Bytes+Length; ++ptr) {
        char buf[3];
        sprintf(buf, "%02x", (*ptr)&0xff);
        ret += buf;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and even a pretty C++ example for the C++ programmers out there. Nice work!

Comment: In the crypto context, base64 is a far more common textual representation for binary data (Such as hashes) than hexadecimal.

Comment: For general and long binary data yes, but I've seen short data and hashes (which are usually short enough) almost always expressed in hexadecimal.

Answer (score 3):

The standard way of representing hashes is as hexadecimal strings.
In C, you can use `printf("%02x", byte)` to get a hex representation of each byte.

An example for MD5, should be easy to adapt it for SHA:

[http://en.literateprograms.org/MD5_sum_(C,_OpenSSL)](http://en.literateprograms.org/MD5_sum_%28C,_OpenSSL%29)

Comment: `$byte`? Did you write much Perl lately? ;)

Comment: Lol for the $byte. I upvoted, but already gave away accept to the first guy.

Comment: Sorry, it's a bad PHP habit :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example for C:

```
//function
void convertSHA1BinaryToCharStr(const unsigned char * const hashbin, char * const hashstr) {
  for(int i = 0; i<20; ++i)
  {
    sprintf(&hashstr[i*2], "%02X", hashbin[i]);
  }
  hashstr[40]=0;
}

//Example call.  hashbin is the 20byte hash array.
char hashstr[41];
convertSHA1BinaryToCharStr(hashbin, hashstr);
printf("%s\n", hashstr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Privacy Enhanced Mail (or PEM) seemed to set the standard for the storage of text representations of crypto data.
PEM stores the actual binary chunk in Base64, but has a text header and footer too.

Comment: PEM defines standard formats for storing keys and certificates in files - and within a certificate a hash will indeed be base-64 encoded - but a hash on its own is usually just displayed in hex. If the has is a key fingerprint it is commonly displayed as pairs of hex digits separated by colons (see e.g. RFC4716)